# Add custom .Ner Identity-based login option tog ADFS

Tags: asp.net-identity, adfs

In my current company we use ADFS for authenticating our users and then provide the applications with a set of claims.
So far we have authenticated users using their AD accounts. However.. we are now in need of making it possible to authenticate as a test user. We are not allowed to create these test users in our AD. So my plan was to extend ADFS with additional sign in options (is it called an identity provider?). I was sort of hoping that it would be easy to add a custom login option that utilizes the .Net Identity "library", but cant find a single article on the internet of how to create a custom login option for ADFS... (Preferebly one that uses .Net Identity). Could someone please point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

ADFS is primarily for authenticating against AD.

You have two options:

- Federate against another IDP and use a test user from there
- Use an [LDAP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/operations/configure-ad-fs-to-authenticate-users-stored-in-ldap-directories) to store the test user

For option 1, you could use identityserver as that can authenticate against [ASP.NET Identity](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/reference/aspnet_identity.html).